# Multiple arguments in a single parameter in jQuery/JS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters, arguments

I have the following code:

```
      function periodClassMaker(period) {
        $('.rsform-block-rsa-formaat-w' + period).parent().addClass('periodselected');
      }
      periodClassMaker(['1','2']);
```

I have also tried:

```
      periodClassMaker('1','2');
```

But in both cases it fails to add the class `periodselected` to `.rsform-block-rsa-formaat-w1` and `.rsform-block-rsa-formaat-w2`

And I don't understand why it fails.

This question was asked earlier but I asked it totally unrelated to my own code. As I did not know if it was at all possible. Everyone commenting me told me to put in my own code so that it was better to comment/reply on specific use cases.

Before asking this previous question I did some trial and error but did not receive an error message and also not the result I wished for. Upon which I went to SO and searched for "multiple arguments for one parameter" and similar search phrases. Many result came up and after reading about a dozen I still did not have a clear view if it was at all possible and if it was on how to do it. Therefore, I posted my own question.

I hope that after the edit the question is useful, clear and that it shows that I did a bit of research before posting.

Comment: Because it is going to perform a `toString()` on the array when it concatenates to the first string.  The assumption being that result is not going to match anything.

Comment: You need to loop over the array and do the action for each element.

Comment: `'.rsform-block-rsa-formaat-w' + ['1','2'] = ".rsform-block-rsa-formaat-w1,2"`

Comment: @Taplar but by looping it requires to write more code then just multiplying ` periodClassMaker('1');periodClassMaker('2');` isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function periodClassMaker(period) {
    $(period.map(it => `.rsform-block-rsa-formaat-w${it}`).join(', ')).parent().addClass('periodselected');
}

periodClassMaker(['1','2']);
```

You can map the individual numbers to each selector string, and then join them by a comma for the logical OR selector.

Comment: I'm sure this works, but it's too compact to be clear. For the sake of demonstration, maybe you should break it down into smaller and easier instructions?

Comment: @Taplar Wow seriously this is beautiful. Did not know that this was possible. Seeing the code makes it easier to understand then when you just said loop. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Well, I did originally envision a real loop, but this also works.

Comment: Ok, I'm taking back what I said, then :)

Comment: @JeremyThille that it is easier to understand is probably me. I have a real hard time reading about code and how it works(in a tutorial kind of way) but when seeing code things seem to click in my head.

Comment: @Taplar I tried it out in the original code and it works like a charm which makes it a lot better readable as I need to call the function in some cases 20 times with 20 different values. Now this can be done in 1 line instead of 20. Accepting in 5 min.

Comment: If I might make a suggestion then.  It would potentially be better, rather than relying on a class that ends with a number, to give them all a shared class, and just use that.

Comment: @Taplar In this case there are 50 periods which all share the same class and each has a individual one. When certain inputs are selected then it needs to make a selection in those classes and for this selection I needed the numbers. Now after the selection and with your code it combines the selected items under one class and from there I can continue.

Do you have an idea why the question gets downvoted. Can I improve upon it?

Comment: I wouldn't take the downvote too hard.  People can downvote for any reason, ranging from they don't think there was research to the question, or they just don't like it.  Personally, I think it was fine.  Perhaps you could have done more debugging to have discovered some of this yourself without asking us, but, meh.  I'm not pulling hairs about it at this point.

Comment: @Taplar ever since I lost one SO account on asking too many downvoted questions I am always getting grey hairs from downvotes. Not that the score is that important to me but the time it takes to create another account is time I can't put into learning more from the amazing world of Code.
And after losing that account I looked up how to write a good question and I always aim to do that from that moment on. Anyway thank you very much for the help and your kind words.

Comment: No problem.  Just remember, any time you have a problem with a code, use `console.log(<expression>)` liberally to see what is going on with your logic, and what it is actually doing.  You should also search engine search for a good javascript debugging tutorial to teach you about your browser debugging tools that will *greatly* help you with exploring your code.  These two things can help you find your own issues before you get to the point where you need to ask S.O.  And at that point if you do still have to ask S.O. you have actions you can show where you definitely made an effort.